# OpenERP form onload

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to create form which related to Employee registration details.
my requirement is like this..
when user click the create button it need to load current employee number+1 for emp no field.
I need to clarify how to call method '_form_onload()'. Means where is the place to call my function.?

here is my code now

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    vals['register_no'] =self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'bpl.worker')
    worker_reg_seq = super(bpl_worker_registration, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
    return worker_reg_seq



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="seq_bpl_worker_registration" model="ir.sequence.type">
            <field name="name">bpl_worker_registration</field>
            <field name="code">bpl.worker</field>
        </record>

        <record id="seq_bpl_worker_registration" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">bpl_worker_registration</field>
            <field name="code">bpl.worker</field>
            <field name="prefix">BPL</field>
            <field name="padding">5</field>
            <field name="number_next">1</field>
            <field name="number_increment">1</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

xml added in data section **openerp**.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose you have to create sequence and on default when create then call the sequence. It will automatically +1 sequence when ever you create new record.

Example:
purchase_sequence.xml put this xml file in **openerp**.py file in data.

```
       <record id="seq_type_purchase_order" model="ir.sequence.type">
            <field name="name">Purchase Order</field>
            <field name="code">purchase.order</field>
        </record>
        <record id="seq_purchase_order" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Purchase Order</field>
            <field name="code">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="prefix">PO</field>
            <field name="padding">5</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record> 



def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
     if vals.get('name','/')=='/':
        vals['name'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order') or '/'
        order =  super(purchase_order, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
        return order
```

So same thing you have to create for you employee number : prefix is what you starting point of sequence for you it will be "EMP": padding is how much long you number upto 5 or 10 what ever
Hope this help you